# How can I logout an open, remote SSH session?

Tags: linux, ssh

I sshed into a Linux machine (bash shell) from a public Windows machine (in our lab) and forgot to log out. I'm now back at my seat in another room and I am too lazy to walk back and log out that session; I can ssh into the Linux machine from my current PC though. Can I force-logout the other session from a new SSH session?

When I ssh to the Linux box from my current PC and type `users` command, I can see that I'm still logged in there; my name is listed twice - one for the current session and another for the session from lab PC.

I don't have root privileges on the said machine, but I guess that shouldn't matter as I'm just trying to log out myself.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Run `tty` on your current session, to find out on which tty you are working, so you do not log yourself out from current session. Run `w`  to show you current users and associated pseudo-terminals(tty). Assuming that you are logged twice and there are no other users on your ssh server, your previous ssh session will be on `pts/0` and current on `pts/1`.  To ditch the session on `pts/0` simply kill processes that are associated to it with

```
pkill -9 -t pts/0
```

Comment: For some reason, `pkill -9 pts/tty-number` didn't work for me; then I found the pid of the process using `ps aux | grep amar` and tried `pkill -9 -P pid` and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: `pkill -9 -t pts/tty-number`. `-t` is the switch to specify `tty`

Comment: Ooops, somehow I missed that `-t` in your answer when I read it first.

Comment: +1, awesome fix.  I just reset my router while I was SSHing to a machine on the same network, and then realized it left that session logged in... This worked perfectly.

Comment: Found this question today (and it works great, so thanks!) but found the `-9` sounded a bit harsh. A simple `-HUP` sufficed for me.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you don't have any other processes you don't want to be 86'ed, you can just do:

```
$ ssh <systemname> pkill -u <yourlogin>
```

And the other session will go away.

Answer (score -1):

You can type:

```
~.
```

You won't see that you typed it but it will close the connection.

Comment: I would like to suggest to refer, https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer will help you to compose better  text.